# Does HandleHttpProcessor supports "CORS"(Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Tags: apache-nifi

I just started working with **HandleHttpprocessor** in Apache Ni-Fi ,trying to figure out if I need to configure anything in HandleHttpprocessor  to  support **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** issue.

Answer (score 3):

**HandleHttpRequest** processor can only accept a request and it does not send any response to the client. Therefore you need to combine it with **HandleHttpResponse** processor in order to send the response back to the client.

[image]

You can set custom headers in **HandleHttpResponse** processor by adding custom properties to it. To do that you can add a dynamic property by clicking the 'plus' sign, then enter its name which will be the name of the custom HTTP header.

Ex: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

[image]